# Where do I find the meaning of ZVT-Protocol Extended Error Code

Tags: windows, payment

We develop a POS-Application and use the ZVT-Protocol to communicate with the paymentterminals. We want to show the status of the paymentterminal inside the app. But for some errors we don't get a intermediate status information. But in the abort command there is a tag for an extended error code. The paymentterminal we test on is a Verfione P400 and the cards are from Intercard.

`1F-16-03-01-27-01`

> 1F16 - extended error code. Variable length, binary. Contains PT manufacturer specific error code. Can be used if no reasonable mapping to ZVT error codes is possible

> 012701 - Value

Now my question is if this is a binary representation is 75521 the correct int value?
And if that is correct where do I need to look to see what this error means? Verifone or InterCard?